# Изменить настройки прокси-сервера в браузере «Safari»?

Tags: macos, proxy, safari, vpn

Требуется изменить настройки прокси-сервера в браузере "Safari" стандартными средствами. Как это можно сделать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Настройки прокси в Safari берутся из системных настроек прокси. Чтобы в них попасть, открываете Safari -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Proxies -> Change Settings.

Comment: Хорошо, благодарю Вас.

Comment: Поставьте галочку возле ответа, если принимаете его. Иначе вопрос будет на сайте висеть как нерешённый